# safecracker hidden field status not working after upgrade (2.6)

Tags: safecracker, upgrade

```
<div class="lead-select">
    <label for="task_lead" class="select" style="margin-top: 12px;">Select Employee</label><br/>
    {field:task_lead}
    <input type="hidden" name="status" value="open">
</div>
<input type="submit" value="Submit">
```

The above code is what i have currently in my template. now the hidden field for changing the status to "open" will not submit. Is there something different in safecracker with the new version.

Just upgraded from 2.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and has been resolved here:
https://support.ellislab.com/bugs/detail/19335

Comment: Yep, this is listed as fixed in [version 2.6.1](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/about/changelog.html#version-2-6-1) so updating should fix the problem.

Comment: FIXED! Thank you!